# Custom ListView ocupando 100% da tela

Tags: android, android-layout

Criei um *Custom Listview* com alguns itens mas como podem ver na imagem abaixo fica um "espaço vazio" na tela.

Gostaria de saber como faço para que os itens ocupem todo o espaço restante na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do Menu.java:

```
public class Menu extends Activity{

private List<MenuItensAndIcons> menuitens = new ArrayList<MenuItensAndIcons>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menulistview);

    CriandoItensMenu();
    CriandoListView();

    final UsuarioLogado usuariologado = (UsuarioLogado) getApplicationContext();

    getActionBar().setTitle(usuariologado.getUsuariologado());
    getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

    }



private void CriandoItensMenu() {

    menuitens.add(new MenuItensAndIcons("Cadastrar", R.drawable.add));
    menuitens.add(new MenuItensAndIcons("Meus Cadastros", R.drawable.consulta));
    menuitens.add(new MenuItensAndIcons("Perfil", R.drawable.neutro));
    menuitens.add(new MenuItensAndIcons("Mapa", R.drawable.mapa));
    menuitens.add(new MenuItensAndIcons("Consulta Avançada", R.drawable.consulta));

}

private void CriandoListView() {

    ArrayAdapter<MenuItensAndIcons> arrayadapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView listamenu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menulist);
    listamenu.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItensAndIcons>{
    public MyListAdapter(){

        super(Menu.this, R.layout.item_view, menuitens);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemview = convertView;

        if(itemview == null){
            itemview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

        }

        //achar o item especifico

        MenuItensAndIcons itematual = menuitens.get(position);

        //preenche os dados do listview

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.ItemIcon);
        imageview.setImageResource(itematual.getIconeMenu());

        TextView Textitem = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.item_TextItem);
        Textitem.setText(""+itematual.getNomeMenu());

        return itemview;
    }


}
```

Código do menulistview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menulist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Código do item_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ItemIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_TextItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ItemIcon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ItemIcon"
        android:text="Text Aqui"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Algum motivo especial de ser um ListView? Essas.informações vem de algum servidor?

Comment: Eu tinha criado um menu com Imageviews, porém com o Listview ficou mais "agradável"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

A única solução que me vem em mente é aumentar o tamanho da cédula. Porém, com um pouco de pesquisa encontrei um caso semelhante e que talvez funcione para você!

Vá para seu arquivo AndroidManifest.xml e adicione o seguinte código:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Espero que ajude!

([Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893199/how-to-make-a-listview-fill-the-usable-screen-area))

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar aqui!

Comment: Sem problemas! se não funcionar me avise e tentaremos encontrar outra solução :)

Comment: O código não funcionou, mas aumentei o tamanho de cada item como você tinha comentado e agora está perfeito!  vlw mesmo cara!

Comment: Fico feliz em saber! magina brother, boa sorte!